# Highlight Text in textarea if not in the array using highlighttextarea plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, highlight

I am using jQuery highlightTextarea plugin to highlight words in an html textarea.

[jQuery highlightTextarea](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/)

It currently highlights those words IN the array,

```
var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'github', 'microsoft', 'yahoo', 'stackoverflow'];
```

But what I want to do is highlight all words which are NOT IN the array. Is there any way I can do this?

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fr7wb2b4/11/

Comment: Would changing the background colour of the textarea and highlighting those words in white help?

Comment: Sorry for my cryptical answer just now, I have updated it, and it worked for me in fiddle! So I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid I have not tought of it, what about this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var words = ['google', 'facebook', 'github', 'microsoft', 'yahoo', 'stackoverflow'];
    $('#textarea').highlightTextarea({
        words: [
           { color : '#F00', 
              words  : ['(.+)'] 
            },         // Make everything highlighted

            { color : '#FFF',
              words : words 
            }          // Make white what matched
        ]
    });
});
```

[Fiddle with it over here](https://jsfiddle.net/fr7wb2b4/13/)

You could also use `words  : ['(\\w+)']` to only highlight words initially

Comment: @anirudh Thanks for the suggestion, I've edited my post.

Comment: `$(...).highlightTextarea is not a function`

Comment: @dude My guess is that the library is not included (correctly) then. If my example stopped working, I suppose the project moved/stopped or the link broke.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the library source, the highlight code: https://github.com/mistic100/jquery-highlighttextarea/blob/master/jquery.highlighttextarea.js#L67

The snippet that does the actual highlighting is:

```
$.each(this.settings.words, function(color, words) {
        text = text.replace(
            new RegExp(that.spacer+'('+ words.join('|') +')'+that.spacer, that.regParam),
            '<mark style="background-color:'+ color +';">$1</mark>'
        );
    });
```

So you can replace the `highlight` function with your own function, and do whatever logic you choose for highlighting  (hurray for open source!)

For example you can copy-paste of the entire function just replace the `$.each(words...` loop with something along:

```
var replaced = '',
    tokens = text.split(' '); 
$.each(tokens, function(ind, token) {
   if (this.settings.words.indexOf(token) != -1) {
     // this token in the text is part of the 'words' - do not highlight
     replaced += token;
   }
   else {
     // this token isn't part of the words - highlight it
     replaced += '<span style="...">'+token+'</span>';
   }
   replaced += ' ';
}
text = replaced;
```